# Mysql query using regular expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

```
SELECT ProductNumber, Name, ListPrice
FROM SalesLT.Product 
WHERE ProductNumber LIKE 'BK-[^R]%-[0-9][0-9]';'BK-M47B-38'
```

I want product that is: `start with 'BK-' followed by any character other 
than 'R', and ends with a '-' followed by any two numerals`.
Above is `ms-sql` query and I want **mysql** version of this query
productNumber is like below :

```
'BK-M47B-40'
'BK-M82B-44'
'FR-R38B-60'
'ST-9828'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent regular expression is pretty similar:

```
SELECT ProductNumber, Name, ListPrice
FROM SalesLT.Product 
WHERE ProductNumber REGEXP '^BK[-][^R].*[-][0-9]{2}$'
```

Key differences:

- `^` and `$` mark the beginning and end of string (otherwise, regular expressions match anywhere in the string.
- `%` --> `.*`
- The {2} is optional but more colloquial in regular expressions for repeating patterns.  Note:  you could also use `[:digit]`, but that's longer to type.
- I forget whether a hyphen is a special character or not, so I just put it in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RLIKE:`

```
SELECT *
FROM Product 
WHERE ProductNumber RLIKE '^BK-[^R].*-[0-9][0-9]$';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a549c/1/0)**</kbd>